# Code to count how many occurrences of an element are found in a string java

Tags: java, arrays, input, count, poker

I have this code here and it makes sense to me that it would print out how many instances occur in the array of the element at array[i]. The count never goes above one, what am I doing wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class poker
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] array = new String[5];
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            array[i] = scan.nextLine();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
                {
                    if (array[i] == array[j]) {
                        count++;
                    }

                }
                if (count >= 3) {
                    System.out.println(array[i] + " exists " + count + " times.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comparison of the datatype `String` won't work unless it's the same instance. 
To just check if the strings are having the same characters you should use `.equals()`. 
Keep in mind that the comparison of `Integer` (not `int`) also works like this. 
The reason behind that is that `String` is a class and not a primitve type.
Also read up on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

So with

```java
if (array[i].equals(array[j])) {
    count++;
}
```

you should be fine.

---

**Additional (more readable) solution**

To give you an advanced approach on how to count same values i created a small sample for you. 
The function you need is `groupingBy`. You group all values of a list in one single attribute while counting the occurences.

**Example**

```java
Map<String, Long> nameAndCount = Arrays.asList(array).stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

for(Entry<String, Long> entry : nameAndCount.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() +  " exists " + entry.getValue()+ " times.");
}
```

Comment: yeah, that was my mistake I forgot to change the operator. when I change it though it gives me a count of 0 instead of 1

Comment: what do you mean by count of 0 or 1? It can't technically give you a count of 0 or 1 since you only output it when the count islarger or equal 3?!

Comment: aha I had the less than operator switched around in BlueJ from experimenting, you are totally right.

Answer (score 1):

this

```
if (array[i] == array[j])
```

will only be true when the reference are the same, if you want to compare the string value use

```
if (array[i].equals(array[j]))
```

Answer (score 1):

To check for equality of strings in java you must use `equals()` function.
Change the line to `if (array[i].equals(array[j]))` and you are good to go!
The operator `==` will return true only when the reference address of the two array elements are same, so that's the reason you never get a count of more than one, as each reference address is an unique one.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.report.automation;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Frequency {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String value[] = { "Mukesh", "Mukesh", "Sasi", "Senthil", "Mukesh", "Mukesh" };
        String match = "Mukesh";
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j <= 5; j++) {
            if (match.equals(value[j])) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```